# Warning: Error in $<-: invalid subscript type 'language' in R script

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to call `renderPlot()` function.

UI.r Page:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("test"),
  sidebarLayout(
    ),
    # Show a plot of the generated distribution
    mainPanel(
       plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
))
```

Server.r Page:

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
plot(cars)
})
```

If i put breakpoint it show following error

`Warning: Error in $<-: invalid subscript type 'language'`

What might be the issue. 
Can anyone help!!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Share more relevant details will be helpful

Comment: @PatelRomil I had issues in plotting the graphs from my R code . It works fine for different projects. It is not working here for me. The script used is basic `renderPlot` for display.

Comment: @RahulK: Make sure to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that people can just copy-paste to find the problems in the code.